# How to use MenuItem.setIntent() in a ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context, android-menu

I have a context menu with a menu item that is supposed to start an intent:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(menuItemText);
    item.setIntent(intent);
```

This used to work, but in newer Android versions, it throws an exception:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Adding this flag would be the easy way out, but I don't want to create a new task since this is supposed to be part of the application's activity stack. The problem is that the system calls `startActivity` which the context of the item, which in this case is a `DecorContext`, not an `Activity`. Since this is all handled by the framework, I have no control over this.

Is there a good solution to this other than setting the flag or handling the operation in `onContextItemSelected`?

Comment: What do you mean by newer android version? Could you specify the version?

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro I see references to the error message in questions dating back to 2010, so I think the error message itself has been around forever, but Android has changed the context that's passed in here. It used to be the Activity, and now it's a separate context, the `DecorContext`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Android uses `DecorContext` for Activities starting in Android 27.

[You can see the change here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/796b8c17d68841b6ee0988966fdd8259ba6629d9%5E%21/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PhoneWindow.java).

You can confirm this in the system level by looking inside of [line 319 in PhoneWindow](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PhoneWindow.java#319). Notice that when the `PhoneWindow` is being constructed from an Activity, `mUseDecorContext` is always set to true. This means that your Menu will be built with the DecorContext every time.

My understanding is that having a separate `DecorContext` for `ContextMenu` is intentional. `ContextMenus` are meant to "float" above content and thus act as a separate menu from the content on which they are being presented.

Depending on what you are using `ContextMenu` for, you might have to consider waiting to build the `Intent` until `onContextItemSelected`, even though you mentioned you would like to avoid that situation. Alternatively, you might have to use some form of IPC to wrap and send your intent back to the Activity. We use the [RxBus](https://github.com/AndroidKnife/RxBus) pattern for this rare use-case. Alternative options are `LocalBroadcastManager` and [EventBus by GreenRobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Hopefully, this helps get you started on alternative solutions. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score -1):

Exception is because you may have not overridden onContextItemSelected method.You have to override onContextItemSelected() as below :

```
@Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    startActivity(item.getIntent());
    return true;
  }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's specifically what I said in my question - that's a way to do it, but it used to work without having to have a custom `onContextItemSelected`. I'm trying to avoid it because the context menu is being populated by a class not related to the activity.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    MenuItem item = menu.add(menuItemText);
    item.setIntent(intent);
}
```

I'm new to android studio applications, so i'm not sure if either will work.